# Using the at and batch utilities with zsh on MacOS

Tags: zsh, macos

I am trying to schedule a one time job with the `at` utility. I am trying:
`at 13:00`, then hitting enter, then
`<name_of_shell_script>`,
then `ctrl+d`.

The top line of my script is: `#!/bin/zsh`

but it is never executed. It executes when run manually, but not when scheduled with the at utility.

Answer (score -2):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `at`, or `batch`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Comment: Hmm... I (largely) agree with you about `cron`, but are you sure the same applies to `at`? The man page on my system says *"The working directory, the environment (except for the variables BASH_VERSINFO, DISPLAY, EUID, GROUPS, SHELLOPTS, TERM, UID, and _) and the umask  are  retained  from the time of invocation."*. Also, why should the command be a *bash* script specifically, rather than the zsh script the OP is already using?

Comment: @steeldriver: I recommend `bash` because it's a simple answer, and is a valid login shell (is in `/etc/shells`). Substitute any shell you like. It's a canned answer that I reuse. These "`cron`, `at`, `batch`, questions are so prevalent that I got tired of rewriting the same explanation. I asked about canned answers on Meta AskUbuntu.

Comment: @steeldriver It's title is "Am I a curmudgeon? Should I STFU?". I've continued the practice.